# Is Nothing comparison gives type mismatch

Tags: vb6

I am trying to check if the 'Listivew.Tag property is nothing'.

I used to do the 'Is Nothing' check universally for all scenarios as first check to avoid errors

Can someone explain how to do it in VB 6?

```
 If Not .lvwLocation.Tag Is Nothing Then
    'COMPANY
    str = str & IIf(Len(.lvwLocation.Tag) > 0, " and u.location_id in " & .lvwLocation.Tag, "")
End If
```

Gives error 'type-mismatch'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Nothing` is a valid value for `Object` variables, and `Is` is the way to compare object pointers.

But a VB6 control's Tag property is a String, and **VB6's String type is not an Object; it's a primitive type**. That means a String variable can't be assigned `Nothing` -- its emptiest possible value is the empty string. (And an Object variable can't be assigned a String value.) For strings just use the same equality/inequality/comparision operators that you use for other primitive (numeric/boolean/date) types:

```
If .lvwLocation.Tag <> "" Then ...
```

Comment: `its emptiest possible value is the empty string` - it isn't. The empty string, `""`, is still a string, although not a very long one, that is allocated somewhere in memory and occupies 6 bytes (four for the BSTR length and two for the Unicode double null terminator). The emptiest possible value is `vbNullString`, a true null pointer to string.

Answer (score 2):

In VB6 it appears that using `Is` [`Nothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445187%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) to compare `Objects` works, Every other data type that I tried did not. In .Net [`Nothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx) represents the default value of any data type and will work like you expect.

```
Dim test as Object

If Not test Is Nothing Then
   /////  
End If
```

Since it appears the data type of th [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445722%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) property in VB6 is a string. I would use something like:

```
If .lvwLocation.Tag <> "" Then      
    /////
End If
```